# Proving that $f(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous...

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'd like to prove this fact which I've read in my textbook:

> Given $f(x)$ continuous and differentiable on $[c, +\infty)$, if
>
> $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = \pm \infty$
>
> then $f(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous.

There is a hint that says to use Lagrange Theorem, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: What is Lagrange Theorem?

Comment: You might have wanted to ask that before answering, @Lucas.

Comment: You are not forced to use a hint.

Comment: No, @Lucas, Inever said you were forced to use it (note, I said, verbatim "You might have wanted to ask that before answering".  "Might have wanted to..." is not even close to "You are forced to use the hint in the question!", *but if it might be relevant,* why wouldn't you consider it (and it's too bad you don't know Lagrange's Theorem, but that's another matter).

Comment: Technically, there are a lot of theorems named after Lagrange, but Wikipedia says the mean value theorem is sometimes called this, which I guess is probably the meaning here. Personally, I've never heard it called Lagrange's Theorem, but apparently it sometimes is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem

Comment: Ok I am wrong. I have post the the most immediate 'proof'  that came to my mind. And of course I know the mean value theorem ;) In France, we only call 'Lagrange's theorem' the one about cardinal of sub-groups.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to Mean Value Theorem, in Italy we use that name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose it is uniformly continuous, for every $c>0$, there exists $d>0$ such that $|x-y|<2d$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|<c$. There exists $M$ such that $x>M$ implies that ${{|f'(x)|}}>{c\over d}$. Take $x>M$, $|f(x)-f(x+d)|=|f'(c_x)||d|>c$.